# Common keyboard shortcut/binding/template for quickly typing '->' & '<-' in texteditor (vim)

Tags: php, haskell, vim, text-editor

What are some common keyboard shortcuts/bindings for typing '->' in the texteditor? Texteditor of choice is vim if that matters.

Where this is coming from: I'm learning Haskell and typing '->' and '<-' seems to be very annoying for me and I was wondering whether there are any common templates/keybindings/shortcuts that seasoned users use in their editors?

I presume that people that use PHP would also be of help here.

Comment: seeing that `->` is two characters I think your out of luck as there is a recording mode to record and then execute your common keys but it is two characters as well.

Comment: Are you using a keyboard layout that doesn't have `<` and `>` anywhere convenient? Otherwise I really don't see what bothers you about those three keystrokes, on a US keyboard it's really no issue.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I think I am using standard us layout (<, > is near the shift key) ... my problem is sort of needing to rely on shift to get to the <,> ...  but like i said I'm new to haskell so maybe it's something that will grow on me naturally?? ... I also realize that I am probably being petty about it (should rather focus on learning the language first than these typing gains  :)) ... but it was a question that was lingering ever since I started

Answer (score 3):

If using Vim, you could try to define some easier to type abbreviation, like this (in command mode):

```
:ia -v ->
```

After this, any `-v` you type while in insert mode will be automatically transformed into a `->`.

See

```
:h abbreviations
```

If at any moment you actually want to type the `-v`, the manual says:

```
To avoid the abbreviation in insert mode: Type part of
the abbreviation, exit insert mode with <Esc>, re-enter
insert mode with "a" and type the rest.  Or type CTRL-V
before the character after the abbreviation.
```

It would also be best to limit these abbreviation to haskell files only, by putting something like this in the .vimrc file:

```
autocmd FileType haskell ia -v ->
```

Comment: Given that there isn't any difference between `-v` and `- v` in Haskell, I guess that OP can just use `- v` instead of `-<ESC>av` :).